# Time complexity of sequential operation with different parameters

Tags: time-complexity

I have a function that has two sequential operations.
I compute the time complexity of these:
O(n) + O(kn^(1-1/k))

What is the total time complexity of the function? Is correct to say that is O(n+kn^(1-1/k))?

Comment: No.  Terms are dropped in Big O.  The only term that matters is the one that makes the function grow the fastest in computation time.

Comment: But in this case the two complexity aren't comparable, so i don't know which term to drop @RobertHarvey

Comment: Which one grows the fastest in computation time?

Comment: it depends on the parameter k

Comment: Of course.  So what is k?

Comment: k is an argument of the function like n

Comment: Well, yes.  But unless you know what k is fixed at, there's no way to know the time complexity.

Comment: I suppose you can leave both terms in.  I've never seen Big O used quite like that before, though I conceded that, if you don't know k, the only way to capture the complexities of this particular operation is to leave both terms in.

Comment: The user of your sequential operations will have to work out that the complexity of the operation is going to depend on what k is.